# sum of array row and col

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have one array,

```
0: (4) ['0', '0', '1', '2']
1: (4) ['0', '0', '2', '2']
2: (4) ['0', '2', '2', '2']
```

Tried to get sum of row and col,

```
   var rowSum = result.map(r => r.reduce((a, b) => a + b));

   var colSum = result.reduce((a, b) => a.map((x, i) => x + b[i]));
```

but getting

```
  row 0012,0022,0222
     col 000,002,122,222
```

Comment: you are adding strings so it just concatenates. parse into int before adding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parse characters to integers:

```js
const result = [
  ['0', '0', '1', '2'],
  ['0', '0', '2', '2'],
  ['0', '2', '2', '2'],
];

var rowSum = result.map(r => r.reduce((a, b) => parseInt(a) + parseInt(b)));

var colSum = result.reduce((a, b) => a.map((x, i) => parseInt(x) + parseInt(b[i])));

console.log(rowSum);
console.log(colSum);
```